# string.split issue

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer-9

The first time I call a function using .split(), it fails, but thereafter it works. Any idea why it is so in IE9? Does anyone have experience with this bug/intricacy and on fixing it? If not that, is there a substitute for .split() that works seamlessly in IE8 and 9? Thanks very much.

EDIT:

the error message that shows up the first time the function is called is:

```
ERROR: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined.
```

EDIT2, Code that brings up error:

```
function parseArgs() {
...
    var urlParams = $(allE[i]).css('list-style-image').split('?')[1].split('_');
...
}
```

Comment: @ColeJohnson definitely, posting now

Comment: The error says it all. The string is null

Comment: Are you sure there is a question mark in that thing? Is it a string even?

Comment: What's the value of `list-style-image`? Does $(allE[i]) always have that property?

Comment: This isn't a problem with `.split()`. You should triple-check your own code before even starting to wonder if there's something wrong with a standard JS method, and then triple-check your own code again. You don't say what `allE[i]` is, but if it is a selector string that is trying to reference elements not yet parsed you'll have problems but then the code would start working if it is called again after the elements are parsed.

Comment: FYI it was a blank string the first time around because the CSS was not yet loaded. It loaded fast enough on all browsers except for IE9. Funnily, IE8 never threw this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the error, test if the string objects are not null. Null does't have members:

```
function parseArgs() {
...
    var urlParams = [];
    var listStyleImage = $(allE[i]).css('list-style-image');
    if(listStyleImage) { // <-- might be null
       var items = listStyleImage.split('?');
       if(items.length>0) urlParams = items[1].split('_');
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Further to this, `.split('?')[1]` might be `undefined`.

Comment: You're welcome. +1 for the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found that it was indeed a blank string.. This is strange because running the function later works. I wonder why IE fails to find the css property the first time around..

Comment: @zallarak - Where is the function first called from when it fails? As per my comment above, if `allE[i]` is a selector string it will only find elements that have been parsed, so e.g., if you call your function from the `<head>` of the document it won't work unless you wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` handler...

Comment: it is wrapped in a $(document).ready() as of now.. it works immediately after, just not the first time.. i even tried setting an interval on it. I wonder what the issue is. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you are trying to `split`is a jQuery object. Perhaps you must try calling a `.html()` or a `.text()` on it first to be able to call split function.

Update:

Okay, my bad. `.css()` doesn't return a jQuery object. Sometimes it returns the value of a css property. It may be a string or not. But anyway, `.split()` can only be called on a string object. Just went through the docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: OP's using `css()` which doesn't return a jQuery object.